# m2eclipse not copying src/main/resources to target

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, m2eclipse

I have a maven project and I have installed m2eclipse. When I build the project, the files inside src/main/resources are not getting copied into target/classes folder.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post you pom.xml, especially the build section

Comment: Tell us your packaging style, and take a look if this POM has a parent where resource directory might have been redefined.

Comment: @Arturs Licis: packaging style is jar and I do not have a parent pom.

Comment: Have you tried running from command-line? But indeed it could be some m2eclipse bug.

Comment: @saravana_pc Do you have any Eclipse (m2eclipse) errors in 'Error Log' view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading all your comments about when resources get copied and when they don't (i.e., everything works fine until Eclipse build gets called), it's very possible that **maven2Builder** is disabled. You could have maven2Nature which neatly configures your classpath, but if you disable maven2Builder, only sources will be compiled and copied to `target/classes` (or whatever is configured in your `.classpath`) due to active Java Builder.

Consider a very simple demo-project configuration (`.project` file in Eclipse project root):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>m2demo</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <!-- 
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
         -->
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

In this example, I have commented **maven2Builder** which results in exactly the same behavior you are getting.

I usually like to see the actual `.project` and `.classpath` file contents, but it all can be accessed via Project Properties. You will find a 'Builders' section in you project properties, and there should be 'Maven Project Builder' checkbox item.

Answer (score 3):

If resources are not copied could because "resources" are not defined properly. You need to indicate to Maven what a resources is.

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <!-- you can define here more than one resource -->
    </resources>
    ...
 </build>
```

Comment: They are copied by default for many of the packing styles, including the default `jar`.

Comment: AS @DuncanJones pointed that is done by default, but resources configuration should be reviewed because maybe current configuration is causing the problem.

Comment: @jddsantaella - that solution is not working. BTW, I do not have a parent pom.

Comment: @saravana_pc can you please post you pom.xml?

Comment: @jddsantaella - it is too big to post here. unfortunately, there is not much space here to post it.

Answer (score 2):

In my project I observed that even if I do specify the resources tag in the pom.xml and configure the maven2Builder the resources are still not copied over. To fix this I manually edited the .classpath file (which exists at the top level of your project) which originally was

```
<classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="java_source">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

to be

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="java_source">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Basically you have to remove the `including="**/*.java"` for non .class files to be copied over.

Comment: That did the trick for me too. I just had to change the "path" attribute to "src". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was an obvious one... Project->Build Automatically was turned off.  The m2e builder which copies resources is called on build.  Turn on automatic build or do a Project->Build All (ctrl-b) to deploy changed resources to target/classes.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and have tried manually starting the build, cleaning, disabling/re enabling maven nature.  I have 10 XML files in my resources folder.  Two of them, never get copied to target/classes.  If I rename them, they get copied.  If I rename them back to the original filename, they do not get copied.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and removed the maven nature from the project and added it back.  Then my resources files were copied correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the problem and it turned out that I had accidentally excluded copying resources with an m2e lifecycle mapping filter:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>resources</goal>
                      <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
```

The "action" should be "execute" instead ...

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem in the form that, while the resources *essentially existed* in the target folder, certain *changes* I had made recently were not available at runtime.

I could solve it by executing Maven's "Update project ..." function.

This flaw never occurred to me before (overtly) and so far I have no clue what's behind this. 
It certainly can be puzzling (it took me quite a while to track down) if the defect leads to *only subtle* mistakes at runtime.